# How to communicate programmatically with the Monero CLI wallet using php?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

I have installed my Monero CLI wallet on my Amazon server with [this help](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-create-a-command-line-monero-wallet).

I want to communicate with this wallet using php. I tried with [this library](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp) but it is not connecting properly.

Can anyone please help me make it work or find another library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to communicate via php with a Monero wallet you have to run Monero Wallet RPC.

```
monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 --disable-rpc-login --wallet-file /path/walletfile
```

If you are using a remote node, simply add to command the `--daemon-host node.moneroworld.com:18089` flag.

That command will build a JSON API avaiable on the `18082` port. You can check if that works by typing `http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc` in your browser.

Let's use the Monero PHP library in order to call some functions in your wallet.

```
<?php
// Example of Monero RPC Connection  
require_once('src/jsonRPCClient.php');
require_once('src/Monero_Payments.php');

// Edit it with your ip and your port of Monero RPC 
$monero_rpc = new Monero_Payments('127.0.0.1','18082');
```

In this way, you created the instance of Monero PHP library.
All the calls are in details on [this page](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html).

For each call of Monero Wallet RPC, there is one function in the Monero PHP library.

Example:

Calling `getaddress` function

```
// Get address from Monero RPC
$address = $monero_rpc->getaddress();
// Print the RPC Response
$monero_rpc->print($address);
```

The RPC response will be printed as JSON. For `getaddress` call, it's

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "address": "42uMGYwvLuUGJzqdWZvr47CGCBz1qNNExZeegcjLPMbaFkBb3XGg6Y1bUwaMbovzGWDXtaASxSBYtaiBB4wuDmrAMCygexH",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "address": "42uMGYwvLuUGJzqdWZvr47CGCBz1qNNExZeegcjLPMbaFkBb3XGg6Y1bUwaMbovzGWDXtaASxSBYtaiBB4wuDmrAMCygexH",
                "address_index": 0,
                "label": "Primary account",
                "used": false
            },
            {
                "address": "82qL8g5h9jvQGroSuDxZASAERKZPf7DQC8784YGmUPrdRp4TTo4KdruDfWUZkmWwWtCzP6buA9yYaWRmXXH7JkAPFXDtwuQ",
                "address_index": 1,
                "label": "",
                "used": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you don't understand PHP library, you can try to call `getaddress` by curl.

```
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getaddress"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Comment: Thank you so much serhack, maxithi for your reply. But i have some more doubt that which path i have to given in the place of "/path/walletfile" in the first command " monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 --disable-rpc-login --wallet-file /path/walletfile ".

I execute it and gave the wallet password then it shows

$ monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 --disable-rpc-login --wallet-file /path/walletfile

Comment: output:

ERROR    wallet.wallet2    src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2499    e || !exists. THROW EXCEPTION: error::file_not_found
WARN     net.http    src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:707    /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2499:N5tools5error15file_error_baseILi1EEE: file not found "/path/walletfile.keys"
ERROR    wallet.rpc    src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1887    Wallet initialization failed: file not found "/path/walletfile.keys"

and i just tried again with the path where my wallet installed in the server, it again shows the same error.

Comment: kindly expect your reply...

Comment: Dear Albert, thank you so much for appreciating my work. You have to put the flag "--walletfile nameofyourwallet", where nameofyourwallet is the path to your wallet. If the wallet is in the same path of monero rpc, you have to put only the name of wallet.